When we navigate to particular url then first home page get loaded then that particular navigation url data get loaded
We have an Angular application, and when the user chooses any path from the menu page, then first it index page, and once the data gets loaded, it will replace the data on another page. So how can we avoid this behaviour?
Here is an example:

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

Here is an example:/ I don't see an example.

You probably didn't set up your routes correctly.  Are you doing some kind of re-direct in the Angular code?  If so, that's the reason.

@toyotaSupra i added a link which first show index page while loading and then it shows original url component. so how to prevent that index or home component when we are directly trying to open different component based on url
